# Why ACTION_CALL not making call programmatically on Android 5?

Tags: android

Problem is I am not getting any error but it's not making call also. It is working Ok on Android KitKat but not on my Lenovo Lollipop(5.0) .

```
try {
      String contact_number="1234567891";
      Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
      callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + contact_number));
          startActivity(callIntent);
    } catch (Exception e) {
          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),e.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

In manifest file I have declared:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

Comment: Your code seems OK. Are you sure it is called/executed? Did you try to put a breakpoint on the first line and debug it?

Comment: @Abdelwahed, i have checked it,s executing but i am not getting output.

Comment: few things to check: do you see anything on your Android monitor when it gets executed? Did you put the permission tag in the correct place in the manifest (before the application tag)? Have you tried the permission DAIL_PHONE and see what you get?

Comment: 1)i didn,t see anything on emulator .2) i have put permission before application tag 3) if i use 'ACTION-DIAL' instead on 'ACTION-CALL' its working.

Comment: Not on emulator. On the IDE. Are you using Android Studio?

Comment: yeas , i m using android studio.in log cat nothing was shown.if i click multiple times at button then it starts call and immediately close screen.

Comment: Perhaps it is the emulator behavior. Try to launch the native phone app on the emulator. Dail any number, call it and see what happens

Comment: i have check on kitkat .it,s working . but on lollipop it,s not making call.dont know what,s problem

Comment: I guess nothing wrong in your code just different android versions emulator reactions. Test it on real phone and it should work.

Comment: actually in  my mobile lenovo (Lollipop 5.0) it didn,t work. but in kitkat mobile it,s working properly.